# Connected Component of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Assume you have a point $a$ in a Hausdorff space $X$.

A subset of $X$ is clopen, if it is open and closed. A subset of $X$ is connected if it is connected in the induced topology.

I know that every connected set containing $a$ is contained in every clopen set containing $a$.

Let $C$ be the union of all connected subsets containing $a$.

Let $D$ be the intersection of all clopen subsets containing $a$.

It is then clear to me that $C\subset D$.

Is it true that $C=D$ ?

This is obviuosly true if $X$ is connected. I have the impression that it is also true if $X$ is locally compact but it is also true for $X=\mathbb Q$ which is not locally compact nor connected. There is this example of a $1$-dimensional totally disconnected space (the points in $\ell^2$ with rational coefficients) which seems to be a good counterexample for many things. But also there it is true that $C=D$. Is it true in general?

Comment: @HeinrichD: Thank you for the comment but this counterexample there is a sequence with two limits so it cannot be Hausdorff...

Comment: @Neslihan: Oh, I forgot that you assumed this here.

Comment: This question will probably be closed, and arguably belongs at Math.SE instead, but you should look up connected components vs. quasi-components. The answer to your question is no, and a Hausdorff example is $X = \{(0, 0), (0, 1)\} \cup \bigcup_{n \geq 1} \{1/n\} \times [0, 1]$ where 
$Conn((0, 1)) = \{(0, 1)\}$, but $QConn((0, 1)) = \{(0, 0), (0, 1)\}$. This is probably in Steen-Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*.

Comment: Incidentally, you are right about connected components and quasi-components coinciding in a locally compact Hausdorff space. See for example Corollary 1.4 in Topology of Manifolds by R.L. Wilder. https://books.google.com/books?id=KmrZjXbqCy8C&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=quasi-component&source=bl&ots=miursr2iG_&sig=nBIOYKLzI_KTgbK5KTk8cyTaiPU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihtJqNlNPQAhUG5IMKHdvuBrY4ChDoAQhHMAg#v=onepage&q=quasi-component&f=false

Comment: @user43208: Thank you for this wonderful example. I did not know that the word I was looking for was quasi-component. Thank you

Comment: @user43208 By the way: I used the week-end to get a copy of Engelking - General Topology, and there is an example of a locally compact space where components and quasicomponents do not agree. So, I was wrong there...